# How to pass mocked PSCustomObject as SQLConnection parameter

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a module with two functions: `OpenDbConnection` and `CloseDbConnection` and trying to write unit tests using pester.
`OpenDbConnection` creates an instance of `System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection`, but I created a mock instead:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
ConnectionString = ''
DataSource = 'TestDataSource'}
```

and when I'm trying to pass this new object into `CloseDbConnection` function as parameter it gives me an error. But when I'm changing parameter type on `CloseDbConnection` function from `System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection` to `PSCustomObject` it does work.

I do not wanna use generic `PSCustomObject` instead of specific `SQLConnection` type. But I also want to be able to write good unit tests.

Comment: What's the specific reason for not creating a mock connection object of the proper type?

Comment: if you mean creating a real instance of SQLCommand then it will do connect to DB, but it's unit tests, so it should not happen

Comment: that's up to your code to not call it.  if you're testing db connections though, you can pass a fake sqlcommand to connect to in-memory sqlite or something.

Comment: my intention is to test my code which is using SQLCOnnection, but I do not need to test that SQLConnection is working properly

Comment: if you're already mocking OpenDbConnection, can you not also mock CloseDbConnection by the same rationale?